# 302 redirect *.at/site redirecting to .comsite

Tags: redirect, htaccess

My WordPress site xy.at/site is redirecting to xy.comsite instead of xy.com/site. Is it possible to fix this in the .htaccess file?

The .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)
Best,

Comment: What's doing the redirecting? If it's not HTAccess then you'll get an infinite redirect loop as WP redirects you then HTAccess redirects back. Perhaps your sites URL is not set correctly?

Comment: xy.at redirects to xy.com which redirects to the ip address of the server where my site is located (as far as I understood). So in wordpress the site URL is www.xy.com (which I also can not change there), the redirection from xy.at to xy.com works fine but once I use the / with the .at site it does not add it to the .com site and I thought I might be able to fix this in the htaccess

Comment: without understanding what is implementing that redirection that's broken, I don't believe it's possible to answer this question. You should be focusing on figuring out the broken part, rather than asking about a particular solution you think might work